# Django template if tag based on current Url value with username

Tags: python, django, django-models, redis, channel

I'm building a chat room app by following a tutorial. When I enter a room, the url looks like this 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/chatroomname/?username=username'. I want to add a different video for every chatroom, I want to do it with and {% if %} tag in the room.html template:

```
{% if request.get_full_path == "/roomname/" %}
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uilkmUoXoLU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
{% endif %}
```

But this only works if the url looks like this 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/chatroomname/', how do I add the username part in the if tag.

If I add an example username and access the room with that username the video doesn't appear.

```
{% if request.get_full_path == "/roomname/?username=exampleusername" %}
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uilkmUoXoLU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    {% endif %}
```

This is the code of the other files:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Message

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html')

def room(request, room_name):
    username = request.GET.get('username', 'Anonymous')
    messages = Message.objects.filter(room=room_name)[0:25]

    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {'room_name': room_name, 'username': username, 'messages': messages})
```

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .models import Message
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Message(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_added',)
```

```
#routing.py
from django.urls import path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/<str:room_name>/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

```
#consumers.py
import json

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

from .models import Message

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()
    
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    
    # Receive message from web socket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message = data['message']
        username = data['username']
        room = data['room']

        await self.save_message(username, room, message)

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': username
            }
        )
    
    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username
        }))

    @sync_to_async
    def save_message(self, username, room, message):
        Message.objects.create(username=username, room=room, content=message)
```

Comment: Such logic does *not* belong in the template, but in the view. A view is focused on business logic, whereas a template focusses on *rendering logic*.

Comment: How do I do this in the views?

Comment: probably you can send video src url in the context based on the url.